# Limit Behaviour Joule-Kelvin Effect for a Van der Waals Gas

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

So the goal is to show that for a Van der Waals gas the Joule-Kelvin coefficient $\mu_{JK}$ has the following limit as $p \to 0$: $$\lim_{p \to 0} \mu_{JK} = \frac{1}{C_p}\left(\frac{2a}{RT} - b\right)$$ 
I went about it as follows. The equation of state for a Van der Waals gas (for 1 mole) is $(p + \frac{a}{V^2})(V - b) = RT$. The Joule-Kelvin coefficient is given by $$\mu_{JK} = \frac{1}{C_p}\left[T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p - V\right]$$
So, to find it I differentiate the equation of state with respect to T while keeping $p$ constant and obtained $$\frac{\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p (2ab-aV+pV^3)}{V^3} = R \implies \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p = \frac{RV^3}{pV^3 - aV + 2ab}$$
Combining substituting the expression for $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p$ into the formula for $\mu_{JK}$ gives $$\mu_{JK} = \frac{1}{C_p}\left[\frac{RTV^3}{pV^3-aV+2ab} - V\right]$$
If I take the limit as the pressure goes to zero I get $$\lim_{p \to 0} \mu_{JK} = \frac{1}{C_p}\left[\frac{RTV^3}{-aV+2ab} - V\right]$$
I do not know how to get rid of the $V$ dependence to make my answer match the one given. Any help?

Comment: Solve for p and substitute into the next-to-last equation.

Comment: That wouldn't remove the V dependence. It just gave me another complicated expression :/

Comment: The next step is to take the limit as V becomes infinite.  What do you get?  I get the desired answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your starting equation, that should be the limit as $\rho \to 0$, not $p\to 0$, where $\rho = 1/V$.  So substitute $\rho=1/V$ in your equations, or, equivalently, just take the limit of your final expression (of course with the van der Waals expression for p substituted) as $V\to \infty$.

Comment: I see! Silly mistake on my part, thank you!

Comment: Who's perfect?  Certainly not me.